# How to retrieve an array of data from Firebase database and populate HTML page with result?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to generate an array of data from my Firebase database and populate a HTML page with the result.

This is the layout of my database:

```
MYAPP
    |_______chat
    |
    |_______users
                |_____2eD8O9j2w
                |             |____email
                |             |____first_name
                |             |____last_name
                |
                |_____7d73HR6d
                |_____9ud973D6
                |_____Kndu38d4
```

I want to be able to get an array of all the "email" and "first_name" fields inside `users`, and then automatically create and populate a list in HTML from this data. (Kind of like creating a contact list, where there would be two divs per row: `<td><div>first_name</div><div>email</div></td>`)

This is my current attempt a populating the HTML page with the data:

**HTML**

(Is it possible to create and populate these rows automatically inside the Javascript, instead of creating empty ones in the HTML code?)

```
<div>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>  
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function createContactList(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var contacts = [];

    // Get a database reference to the users section
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/users');
    ref.on("value", function(element) {
        return function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());    

            // Loop through each HTML tag
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

                element.innerHTML = snapshot.val();
                var tester = snapshot.val();

                console.log(tester.email); // This returns "undefined"
                console.log(snapshot.val()); // This returns a list of User IDs
                console.log(snapshot.val().email); // This returns "undefined"
                console.log(snapshot.val(email)); // This shows the error: ``firebase Uncaught ReferenceError: email is not defined``

                var createarraytest = snapshot.email;
                contacts.push({email: createarraytest});    
            }
        }(elements[i]),
        function (errorObject) {  // Deal with errors
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
    }
              console.log(contacts);
}
```

When I run this function, it the following list appears on the HTML page:

```
[OBJECT OBJECT]
[OBJECT OBJECT]
[OBJECT OBJECT]
[OBJECT OBJECT]
[OBJECT OBJECT]
```

`console.log(snapshot.val());` shows a list of the randomized user IDs. In an attempt to access the `email` and `first_name` data for each ID I've tried the following:

```
var tester = snapshot.val();
console.log(tester.email); // This returns "undefined"

console.log(snapshot.val().email); // This returns "undefined"
console.log(snapshot.val(email));  // This shows the error: ``firebase Uncaught ReferenceError: email is not defined``
```

I'm used to using arrays in Javascript with an SQL database, but I don't know how to access the data contained within the random user ID strings Firebase creates in this noSQL database.

I've tried following the docs and the answer posted here: [Proper way to store values array-like in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124406/proper-way-to-store-values-array-like-in-firebase) but I've so far been unable to get it to work.

Any help getting this to work would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, so I'm not sure which part you're asking about. But the way you retrieve your data and loop over it will definitely cause problems.

To retrieve data you use a `value` event, which returns a snapshot with a collection of all the requested child nodes. To loop over those children, use `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
ref.on("value", function(element) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+': '+child.val());
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = child.val().email + " --- " + JSON.stringify(child.val());
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
});
```

I recommend listening for `child_added` events instead, since it simplifies your code and will make it easier to respond to other events (such as `child_deleted`) later:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
ref.on("child_added", function(child) {
  console.log(child.key+': '+child.val());
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerText = child.val().email + " --- " + JSON.stringify(child.val());
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

From reading your questions, I get the impression that you're trying to learn both Firebase and web development at the same time. That's a great and powerful combination of technologies, that will allow you to build some awesome apps. But taking on both at the same time, means that your questions tend to lack some focus. It is unclear whether you are stuck with the Firebase parts or the HTML parts.

I highly recommend that you take the [Firebase Codelab for web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/), which builds a chat application and gives you the HTML pieces already. Or build a web chat app without Firebase first. Yes, it will be boring and just manipulating local arrays of data. But it will lead to more focussed questions, which make it easier for us to help you. And then, once you've mastered the web aspects, you can add Firebase for the realtime data goodness.

Comment: Hi @frank-van-puffelen thank you so much for your answer! I've taken your advice and have completed the tutorial you mentioned. It's been really helpful. You're correct about me trying to learn web development and Firebase at the same time, both are really interesting and hopefully I'll be able to ask more concise questions in the future. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Web development + Firebase are a powerful combination, so you could've picked worse. ;-)  Keep on hacking and post back when you have another question.